# How to install firmware for Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: cnc

I want to run cnc_ctrl_v1 file to install firmware for Arduino Mega 2560 to control a Maslow CNC wood cutting device, but compiling and running this firmware gives the error with the following output (partially in Spanish):

```
El Sketch usa 57294 bytes (22%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 253952 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 2009 bytes (24%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 6183 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 8192 bytes.
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I was confirming that I follow the steps in Manual: https://www.maslowcnc.com/assemblyguide. I did not find information to this version of the error in Google and another Stack Overflow post.

I hope CNC is a correct tag for this question.

I did set it to longer output later, results are here:

```
FQBN: arduino:avr:mega
Using board 'mega' from platform in folder: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6

Detectando las librerías usadas...
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\variants\\mega" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.cpp" -o nul
Alternativas para Servo.h: [Servo@1.2.0]
ResolveLibrary(Servo.h)
  -> Candidatos: [Servo@1.2.0]
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\variants\\mega" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\libraries\\Servo\\src" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.cpp" -o nul
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Axis.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Encoder.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\GCode.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Kinematics.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Motion.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Motor.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\MotorGearboxEncoder.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\NutsAndBolts.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\PID_v1.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Probe.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Report.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\RingBuffer.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Settings.cpp
Alternativas para EEPROM.h: [EEPROM@2.0]
ResolveLibrary(EEPROM.h)
  -> Candidatos: [EEPROM@2.0]
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\SimavrSerial.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Spindle.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\System.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Testing.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\TimerOne.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\avr\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\mbed\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\megaavr\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\nrf52\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\renesas\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\sam\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\samd\Servo.cpp
Using cached library dependencies for file: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo\src\stm32f4\Servo.cpp
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\variants\\mega" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\libraries\\Servo\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\libraries\\EEPROM\\src" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\builtin\\tools\\ctags\\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\preproc\\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compilando el sketch...
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Motion.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Axis.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\NutsAndBolts.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Encoder.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Kinematics.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\PID_v1.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Motor.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\GCode.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\MotorGearboxEncoder.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Probe.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Report.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\RingBuffer.cpp.o
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_MEGA2560 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\variants\\mega" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\libraries\\Servo\\src" "-IC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\libraries\\EEPROM\\src" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.cpp.o"
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Settings.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\SimavrSerial.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Testing.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\Spindle.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\TimerOne.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\sketch\System.cpp.o
Compilando librerías...
Compilando librería "Servo"
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\stm32f4\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\nrf52\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\sam\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\samd\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\renesas\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\mbed\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\avr\Servo.cpp.o
Utilizando archivo previamente compilado: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\libraries\Servo\megaavr\Servo.cpp.o
Compilando librería "EEPROM"
Compilando el núcleo...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\cores\arduino_avr_mega_cpu_atmega2560_933cf1e7cb2be48893f40a83209fd279\core.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -Wall -Wextra -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega2560 -o "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Axis.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Encoder.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\GCode.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Kinematics.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Motion.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Motor.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\MotorGearboxEncoder.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\NutsAndBolts.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\PID_v1.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Probe.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Report.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\RingBuffer.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Settings.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\SimavrSerial.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Spindle.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\System.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\Testing.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\TimerOne.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\sketch\\cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\avr\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\mbed\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\megaavr\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\nrf52\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\renesas\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\sam\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\samd\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66\\libraries\\Servo\\stm32f4\\Servo.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/..\\..\\cores\\arduino_avr_mega_cpu_atmega2560_933cf1e7cb2be48893f40a83209fd279\\core.a" "-LC:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66" -lm
C:\Users\cnc\Desktop\CNC\Firmware-1.26\cnc_ctrl_v1\System.cpp: In function 'setupAxes':
C:\Users\cnc\Desktop\CNC\Firmware-1.26\cnc_ctrl_v1\System.cpp:256"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.eep"
:12: warning: 'aux4' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   ProbePin = aux4;                 // use this input for zeroing zAxis with G38.2 gcode
            ^
C:\Users\cnc\Desktop\CNC\Firmware-1.26\cnc_ctrl_v1\System.cpp:258:10: warning: 'aux2' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   pinMode(LaserPowerPin, OUTPUT);
          ^
C:\Users\cnc\Desktop\CNC\Firmware-1.26\cnc_ctrl_v1\System.cpp:255:26: warning: 'aux1' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   SpindlePowerControlPin = aux1;   // output for controlling spindle power
                          ^
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.hex"

Usando librería Servo con versión 1.2.0 en la carpeta: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\libraries\Servo 
Usando librería EEPROM con versión 2.0 en la carpeta: C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\libraries\EEPROM 
"C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-size" -A "C:\\Users\\cnc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.elf"
El Sketch usa 57294 bytes (22%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 253952 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 2009 bytes (24%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 6183 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 8192 bytes.
"C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega2560 -cwiring "-PCOM4" -b115200 -D "-Uflash:w:C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B49C514541725A6C562143D121DA5F66/cnc_ctrl_v1.ino.hex:i"

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\cnc\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : wiring
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```